# how could i solve resolution issues on designing fullscreen website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, resolution

When I made my fullscreen website I was working on resolution 1920*1080, but when the resolution get smaller specifically with height on the laptop screen scroll bar appeared and the footer gets down I know the problem with the padding on the page and margins but I tried to make media query "@media (max-height)" it didn't work as I thought.

I think that there is a way to solve it with a few steps but, I don't know please support me.

Thanks,
P.S. sorry my poor english

Comment: hundreds of ways. CSS like it seems your doing, or window.resize() and resize everything accordingly. Without an example its hard to tell you exactly what you need but there are thousands of examples online which you can follow. Just research :)

Comment: You might not be aware of the basic design principles and approaches regarding responsive websites. CSS is usually configured using media queries for a specific screen size (width of the screen). [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is a tutorial of how to implement the basic responsive principles.

Comment: Post something that isnt working, and your try to make it work, then we tell you what you're doing wrong and how it can be better.

Comment: i know its wrong to use  "@media (max-height)" but i need a solution. i searched alot but i dont know what can i write to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the code that you used, this is an example of the way that you can use it, you can refer to [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
   .container {
       padding:0;
   }
}
```